# How to Randomize Between two Values?

Tags: c#, game-development

I am trying to make this Vector2 have the first value either be equal to -7 or 7. The second value to be -5, 5 or anything in between. I can not seem to figure out how to make the first value either -7 or 7 and nothing in between. Please help

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(Random(-7,7) , Random.Range(-5,5));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Next` to generate randomly either a -1 or 1 like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomSign = r.Next(2) * 2 - 1;
```

To make that a 7 or -7, you just multiply by 7:

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(randomSign * 7 , Random.Range(-5,5));
```

Because this seems like Unity, here is how to do it with the Unity `Random.Range` method:

```
int randomSign = Random.Range(0, 1) * 2 - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
 int[] numbers = new int[] { -7, 7 };
  var random = new Random();
  vrb2d.velocity = new Vector2(numbers [random.Next(2)] , Random.Range(-5,5));
```

Put all numbers in a vector and pick randomly the index. Easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to your question:

```
Random random = new Random();

// Get a value between -5 and 5. 
// Random.Next()'s first argument is the inclusive minimum value, 
// second argument is the EXCLUSIVE maximum value of the desired range.
int y = random.Next(-5, 6);

// Get value of either 7 or -7
int[] array = new int[] { 7, -7 };
int x = array[random.Next(array.Length)]; // Returns either the 0th or the 1st value of the array.

rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);
```

It is important to know that the **random.Next(-5, 6);** returns a value **between -5 and 5**. Not -5 and 6, as it seems at first sight. (Check the function's description.)